# How to avoid flattening a shrinkwraped object?

Tags: modeling

I want to bend a scale mesh around a fish body, so that it fits perfectly but doesn't become flat as if I would use *Shrinkwrap* modifier.
So how can I shrink it to the body without making it flat so the scales are still 3D?

So here is an image of the body and the scales. The fish will not swim or be animated, just normal, so the scales has to follow the curves of the body without any edges or suchlike.

[image]

[image]

Regards

Comment: please, in order to understand, post some reference image or test you did and didn't worked

Comment: So here are some images, I think I found what I was searching for...https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?406295-Addon-Projection-Ops
After installing I dont see any options to use and behind the addon in Blender there is a warning sign, but I dont know for what.

Answer (score 1):

I would add the scales to the fish mesh using a particle system. You can create a couple of separate scale objects, and then use the particle system to instantiate those on the fish skin.

Answer (score 0):

You can render an orthographic image of your texture tile.

On your fish body, you can add a camera that projects strait on to your fish body.

On the fish mesh, add a UV project modifier.

Select your rendered texture as the image source.

Be sure to check override image.

Now use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to get into texture mode.

Move your camera closer or further away from the fish body to get a general overall scale.

Once you are happy with the overall rotate the head of your camera about 'Z' toward the head of the fish.

You will notice that the more you rotate, the smaller the scales will become at the tail, and the larger they will become at the head.

Once you have the perspective that you like:

Apply the Modifier.

Now add a displace modifier, using the same texture image, and making sure that the mapping is set to UV coordinates, adjust your strength way low. Probably like 0.02.

Then you should see that your texture is mapped to your fish body.

If this still looks to blocky - you will have to subdivide a lot to give the mesh the amount of detail that it needs to be displaced correctly (subdivide as necessary - This can get really memory intensive so be careful and save every step of the way).

Here's the result of all of this.

[image: result]

And here is the image I used from pixabay (I just desaturated it).

[image: Base Image]